# Bootstrap 4 Carousel responsive (image and text)

Tags: css, html, carousel, bootstrap-4

I've copy and paste the Carousel code example of the Bootstrap 4 official website, but I've realised that this resource isn't responsive.

You can try in this page:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/carousel/
If you resize or open using a small cellphone for instance, the text will disapear. The image isn't responsive as well...

What I need do to make the image and the text responsives?

The HTML code:

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-left">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block text-right">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    /* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 3rem;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel-item {
  height: 32rem;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 32rem;
}


/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: .75rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 5rem 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -.05rem;
}


/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 7rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes using `object-fit:cover` in css for images is great when image cropping is allowed in smaller screens and full image in larger ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the class d-none the text displays when you resize the window. Here's more info on display properties: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: I've removed the class "d-none" as you suggest me and now the text appears, but When I decrease the screen the text became misaligned ... how can I fix that? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since your using bootstrap library, they have a class to simplify an image being responsive all you have to do is include the class `"img-responsive"` to the image you have. 
Ex:

```
<img class="first-slide" class="img-responsive" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
```

Comment: I've tried write "img-responsive" but doesn't work... Then, I've used the tag  "img-fluid" and works! thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`.img-fluid` is the way to go if it is bootstrap 4 you're using.